# Matlab strsplit by space and quotes

Tags: matlab

I have a string of variable names as shown below:

```
{'"NORM TIME   SEC, SEC, 9999997" "ROD FORCE, LBS, 3000118" "ROD   POS, DEG, 3000216" P_ext_chamber_press P_ret_chamber_press "GEAR#1 POS INCH" 388821 Q_valve_gpm P_return 3882992 "COMMAND VOLTAGE VOLT"'}
```

the double quotes are for the variable names with spaces or special characters between the words" and a single word variable doesn't have any quotes around them.  The variables are separated by one space.  Some variable names are just numbers.

At the end, I want to create a cell with strings as follows:

```
{'NORM_TIME_SEC_SEC_9999997','ROD_FORCE_LBF_3000118','ROD_POS_DEG_3000216','P_ext_chamber_press','P_ret_chamber_press','GEAR#1_POS_INCH','3388821','Q_valve_gpm','P_return','3882992','COMMAND_VOLTAGE_VOLT'}
```

Comment: The number of double quotes is odd (as in 2&times;n+1 = odd). Isn't this messing with your variable name grouping?

Comment: I this @Suever edited it.  The last variable yz doesn't have double quotes and that's what makes this problem tricky.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `regexp` to first split it into groups and then replace all space with `_`

```
data = {'"abc def ghi" "jkl mno pqr" "stu vwx" yz"'};

% Get each piece within the " " 
pieces = regexp(data{1}, '(?<=\"\s*)([A-Za-z0-9]+\s*)*(?=\"\s*)', 'match');

%   'abc def ghi'    'jkl mno pqr'


% Replace any space with _
names = regexprep(pieces, '\s+', '_');

%   'abc_def_ghi'    'jkl_mno_pqr'
```

**Update**

Since your last variable isn't surrounded by quotes, you could do something like the following

```
pieces = strtrim(regexp(data, '[^\"]+(?=\")', 'match'));
pieces = pieces{1};
pieces = pieces(~cellfun(@isempty, pieces));

% Replace spaces with _
regexprep(pieces, '\s+', '_')
```

Comment: This smells like dynamic variable naming. My nose is already itching, and it's seldom wrong.

Comment: `data = {'"abc def ghi" "jkl mno pqr"'};`  and then `data=cell2mat(data);` ? no?

Comment: @Sardar_Usama It's not clear if it's really a cell array. Also `regexp` and `regexprep` also accept cell arrays

Comment: @Adriaan, this is not a dynamic variable naming.  This is an old test data and someone decided to name the variable names with commas and spaces.  The alphabet letters are just to show the point.  The variable names with commas and spaces have double quotes and rightfully so to indicate it's one string, but a single word variable doesn't have to have quotes around them. Sardar, the data is in an ascii format and when I bring it into Matlab with %s, the data comes in as a cell.

Comment: @Eric Updated to deal with missing `"`

Comment: @Suever, Your suggested solution above didn't quite work.  I omits the unquoted variable name.  I don't know if it's possible, but what will really work well for me with what I'm dealing with is to tell Matlab to replace all spaces with an underscore "within a pair of double quotes", but not the spaces outside a pair.

Comment: @Eric I updated it with the exact data you provided. What about it is not what you expect?

Comment: @Suever First of all.  I really appreciate your help.  There is no double quote after yz in the data cell: "abc def ghi" "jkl mno pqr" "stu vwx" yz'.  yz gets omitted.  I'd like to expand the cell little longer just to make sure the robustness of a solution: data = {'"abc def ghi" "jkl mno pqr" "stu vwx" yz abc "def hgi ald" "adf dkdjf" ccc ddd'}

Comment: @Eric It would be helpful if you would update your example string in your question then to actually represent the data you have as it *does* have that trailing `"`

Comment: @Suever the original question has been updated with more realistic data example.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up forcing myself to study little bit on regular expression and the following seems to be working well for what I'm trying to do:

```
regexp(str,'(\"[\w\s\,\.\#]+\"|\w+)','match')
```

Probably not as robust as I want since I'm specifically singling out a certain set of special characters only, but so far, I haven't seen other special characters other than those in the data sets I have.

Answer (score 0):

str = {'"abc def ghi" "jkl mno pqr" "stu vwx" yz"'};

Then

```
str_u = strrep(str,' ','_');
[str_q rest] = strtok(str_u,'"');
str_u = rest;
while ~strcmp(rest,'')
    [token rest] = strtok(str_u,'"');
    if ~(strcmp(token,'_')||strcmp(token,''))
        if strcmp(token{1,1}(1),'_')
            token{1,1} = strrep(token{1,1},'_','');
        end
        str_q = [str_q, token];
    end
    str_u = rest;
end
```

The resultant cell array is str_q, which will give the names of the variables

str_q = 'abc_def_ghi'    'jkl_mno_pqr'    'stu_vwx'    'yz'